# What is the large popup view in UIKit called?

Tags: ios, iphone, view, popup, uikit

I am writing an iPhone application where I want to utilize the large popup view, but I don't know what it's called. I have a picure on it.

[image: Large popup view]

I mean the middle square that isn't shadowed. It has the title "Köp mer utrymme". I know it's from an iPad, but I'm pretty sure a similiar one exists on the iPhone, for example, the iTunes-store agreements. I looked in [Apple's UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857), but I couldn't found it there.

**Does anyone know what it's called or how to get it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view on the picture is presented modally. When presenting a view modally, you can customize the presentstion style. The default style is *UIModalPresentationFullscreen*, but the style in the picture is *UIModalPresentationFormSheet*.

To present a view controller in that style, you first create an instance of the view controller and then set its style.

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note that isn't possible to change the presentation style for iPhone. (I must have imagined that the iTunes-store agreement wasn't fullscreen.)

Answer (score 2):

On iPad it could be a `UIPopoverController` with a custom view controller inside it, or a modally presented view controller. You can't use that on iPhone (at least not in the same way, popovers don't exist and modal views are full screen).

On iPhone you could use a `UIAlertView`, or you could search github / cocoacontrols for a suitable 3rd party implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use KGModal.h and KGModal.m class.  For a PopVieController is is best ....and easy to make and add control over it and no need to set frame for orientation ....
   Find these 2 Class   (KGModal.h and KGModal.m)...